# AWS Pinpoint error after updating APNS certificate with Expo

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, expo, aws-pinpoint

After sending a new build to the app store, the push notifications for my app are no longer working. During the build, expo made a new APNS certificate, and now when I try to push a notification to users, I get the following error message.

> "'{"errorMessage":"Invalid
>   Credentials","channelType":"APNS","pushProviderStatusCode":"403","pushProviderError":"InvalidProviderToken","pushProviderResponse":"{\"reason\":\"InvalidProviderToken\"}"}'"

I get the same error message when attempting to send myself a notification through the AWS Console. I tried to update my push notification credentials on expo, but get a similar error:

> ? Path to P8 file: /Users/REDACTED/Downloads/AuthKey_D3QREDACTED-1.p8
>   ? Key ID: REDACTED ? Apple Team ID: REDACTED Unable to validate Push
>   Keys due to insufficient Apple Credentials

I tried following every thread I could find online about the error and verified that I had the right Team ID and Key ID, but it still does not work.

Happy to provide more info if needed, and thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to regenerate a new .p8 file and upload it to AWS pinpoint

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue recently, and no matter how many times I tired to "Edit" the APNs configuration it would not work. Eventually I just removed APNs setting from PinPoint, saved it, and then set it up again fresh.
Now it works.